# ¿Como recoger la respuesta de una llamada ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Me gustaría recoger la respuesta de la siguiente llamada ajax:

```
function prueba(callback){

       $.ajax({
            url: '/services/traps/view/',
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken
            },
            success: callback ,
            error: function(qXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(errorThrown);
                console.log(qXHR);
                console.log(textStatus);

            },
        });
    };

function mycallback(data){
  //mi código
};

var mydata = prueba(mycallback);
```

En este caso, *mydata* devuelve undefinded. Quiero recogerla para manipularla después con jquery.

Comment: En esa respuesta que escribí hace algunos días, explica lo que puedes hacer.

Answer (score 2):

Hay varios problemas en el código por los que vas a obtener `undefined` en la variable `mydata`:

1. La función `prueba` no devuelve nada

   Estás asignando a `mydata` el valor de la función  `prueba`... pero prueba no devuelve nada, por lo que `mydata` será siempre `undefined`.
2. Quieres realizar una asignación síncrona de un valor asíncrono

   Éste es el verdadero problema. La función AJAX se ejecuta de manera asíncrona (se realiza la llamada al servidor y se ejecuta success/error cuando vuelve la respuesta) pero la asignación es síncrona; por lo tanto, incluso si `prueba` devolviera un valor, no funcionaría porque ese valor aún no se habría asignado antes de devolverlo.

Posibles soluciones: puedes cambiar la función para que devuelva un valor y realizar la llamada AJAX de manera síncrona (haciendo `async:false`). De esta manera te aseguras de que el valor sí estará ahí cuando lo devuelvas. **Esta opción no es la mejor y no es la recomendada**.

Otra alternativa mejor sería empaquetar el código que haga uso de la variable `mydata` en una función y llamarla en `mycallback` (donde se asigna el valor de `mydata`):

```
function prueba(callback){

       $.ajax({
            url: '/services/traps/view/',
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken
            },
            success: callback ,
            error: function(qXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(errorThrown);
                console.log(qXHR);
                console.log(textStatus);

            },
        });
    };

function mycallback(data){
  //mi código
  mydata = data;
  operacionesConMyData();
};

function operacionesConMyData() {
    // mover aqui las operaciones que necesiten mydata
}

// llamada al AJAX
prueba(mycallback);
```

Comment: Deberías poner un `var mydata` para que el OP y los futuros lectores sepan en que ámbito léxico se debe declarar esa variable. De lo contrario podría intentar declararla en el lugar incorrecto y pensar que la solución que le diste no funciona ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Sin utilizar callback. podes tomar el valor del retorno en el success

```
function prueba(callback){

       $.ajax({
            url: '/services/traps/view/',
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken
            },
            success: function (retorno) {
          // El retorno contendra la información 

        },
            error: function(qXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(errorThrown);
                console.log(qXHR);
                console.log(textStatus);

            },
        });
    };
```

Comment: ¿Cómo responde esto a la pregunta? OP hace lo mismo pero de manera diferente (la función `mycallback` es llamada cuando ocurre el success y el parámetro `data` es equivalente a `retorno`)

Comment: Y cual es el error?, supuestamente las dos funciones hacen lo mismo. yo aporte una alternativa. No tengo el código completo para probar si funciona o no.

Comment: El error está en el código mostrado, no hace falta código adicional